# Is "I think I could do it too" natural in this context?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A man is in a session with his therapist and very annoyed with him.

Man: *It's an easy job you've got, huh?*

Therapist: *You think so?*

Man: *Yeah. **I think I could do it too.***

Therapist: *You do?*

Man: *Absolutely. If it all it takes is to ask a lot of idiotic questions, then sure I could.*

Is the highlighted question completely natural/naturally phrased in the context?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  But there's another mistake "if it all takes" should be "if all it takes"

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted answer is natural, however the following sentence is not

> If it all it takes is to ask a lot of idiotic questions, then sure I could.

should be:

> If all it takes is to ask a lot of idiotic questions, then sure I could.

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but it would be better if you removed "it" altogether. The strike-through is almost invisible. It took me a whole minute to realize what the difference was!

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly "natural", but has two possible senses.

It could mean "Yes, I think that, like you,  I could do it".

Or it could mean "Yes, I think it is easy, and also that I could do it".

If you consider these carefully you will see that they do not mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "do" in "I think I could do it too" is what makes the sentence a little awkward since "doing" a job kind of implies that the job is merely a task (like "doing" the dishes) rather than an occupation.

Maybe something along the lines of "I think I could manage it too" would fit better.

Even more, since the man is annoyed, you can make the sentence a little more aggressive: "I think I could do it better"/"I think I could take it too".

Hope this helps!